# Как организовать локальное хранение данных?

Tags: c#, база-данных, xml, autocad

Занимаюсь разработкой десктопного приложения на C# (плагин автокад), работа внутри которого организована по проектам, данные которых хранятся сейчас в файлах xml. Соответственно, при каждом действии пользователя на чертеже происходят изменения в этих файлах проекта. Быстродействие такой "базы данных" оставляет желать лучшего, в связи с чем возникла мысль перейти на реляционную базу данных с использованием Entity Framework. Вопрос состоит в следующем: программа устанавливается с инсталлятора, как развернуть на устройстве пользователя локальную базу данных и подсоединиться к ней (могут ли при этом возникнуть конфликты прав доступа)? Или же быть может, я смотрю не в том направлении и быструю базу данных можно организовать проще?

Comment: Ну а сейчас вы XML-ки за собой таскаете? С правами доступа к ним всё нормально?

Comment: На вопрос нельзя ответить однозначно да или нет, поскольку разные СУБД используют разные виды авторизации. Если в общем - в нескольких случаях возможны проблемы, но в 90% случаев (учитывая что файлы читаются) проблем не будет. Рассматривать каждый случай отдельно - не вижу необходимости.

Comment: Они создаются локально при создании проекта, с ними конечно никаких проблем быть не может. А вот при установке какой нибудь СУБД могут начаться проблемы. Например, в случае если у пользователя ограничены права в  системе

Comment: А почему XML медленно? Вы ведь не перечитываете его каждый раз, а грузите в память при старте? Где тогда просадка производительности?

Comment: Т.к. файл должен быть синхронизирован с чертежом - то да, каждый раз перечитывается, изменяется, и т.д.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы избежать проблем с развёртыванием, рекомендую использовать любую встраиваемую БД. Например, [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/). В Интернете много материалов по ней. Есть статьи на популярных ресурсах, [можете ознакомиться](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149356/).

К сожалению, не зная подробностей вашей задачи и информации о хранимых типах, сложно предложить что-то ещё. Вполне возможно, что в вашем случае хватило бы и просто бинарного файла, размеченного на области (если ваши данные только изменяются, а не увеличиваются в объемах). То же самое касается и реляционных баз данных. Возможно, эти связи вам и не нужны? Возможно, и SQL вам не нужен и больше подойдёт [NoSQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Кроме того, ваше решение хоть и далеко от идеала, но вполне себе может использоваться и масштабироваться в текущем варианте. Вы можете разбить хранилище на множество мелких файлов, генерация и сохранение которых будет пролетать моментально.

И главное - вы можете уйти от синхронной модели сохранения данных (что стоит сделать в любом случае) и сохранять данные в фоновом процессе. Разумеется, это потребует от вас дополнительных телодвижений для обеспечения консистентности данных в случае неожиданного отключения системы. Но в первом приближении сохранить новое состояние в памяти и пнуть фоновый поток, который сохранит его в файл, а после окончания проверит, не нужно ли эту операцию повторить - вполне себе решение, которое не будет тормозить работу пользователя, и будет приводить к проблемам только в случае аварийного завершения процесса (выключения электричества, убийство процесса и т.д.)